# python log pops up on console

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am using below configuration for logging in python,

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(r'/var/log/resource_checker.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(name)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This works well for me. However if I add `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` with existing logging configuration, all my logs pops up on screen screen (with additional DEBUG logs, which is good to have for me) and logfile does not populate at all.

how can i push those logs back to log file as my older config.?

Comment: Are you saying you want the console to print logs with level `logging.DEBUG` and still have your existing logger write to the file as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will log everything to a file, all from the `logging.basicConfig`:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='/var/log/resource_checker.log',
    format='%(asctime)s : %(name)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s'
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```